# HIbernate HQL unexpected token

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I have following Hibernate query:

```
String HSQL = "from Page as p "
  + "where not exists (from Link as l where l.dealId = p.id) "
  + "and p.userId = :userId";

return (List<Deal>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
  .createQuery(HSQL)
  .setParameter("userId", userId)
  .list();
```

But on method `.createQuery(HSQL)` it fails with following exception

```
[ ERROR ] [12.11.2019 13:19:10] --- U: I: S: --- org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker: line 1:137: unexpected token: .
[ ERROR ] [12.11.2019 13:19:10] --- U: I: S: --- org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker: line 1:137: unexpected token: .
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: .
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromClassOrOuterQueryPath(HqlBaseParser.java:1972) [hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromRange(HqlBaseParser.java:1499) [hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1343) [hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1063) [hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:748) [hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.subQuery(HqlBaseParser.java:3910) [hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.quantifiedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3515) [hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.unaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3373) [hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.multiplyExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3273) [hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
...
```

My version of Hibernate is 5.4.1.

What is wrong with the query?

Comment: from what I remember there's no need to use `as` before stating an alias in HQL queries.

Comment: what is the type of `dealId`

Comment: can you please share your entities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your entity `dealId` is of type `Page` not of type `Long`, so instead you can use  :

```
"where not exists (from Link as l where l.dealId = p) "
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Actually, `SELECT` is supposed to be optional in HQL, at least for the outer query this is definitely the case.  See here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-from

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, I agree it is optional, there are part in your question I can't understand sorry, can you clarify please :)

Comment: thanks, this led me to solution. The entity did not have dealId property , but the deal itself. So if I did `l.dealId = p` it started to work.